# Apply nextgen-gallery lightbox effect

Tags: images, templates, plugin-nextgen-gallery, customization

I wrote a Template which uses custom-fields via WP-MoreFields plugin.
And there I add an image. In my template I display that Image like this:

```
<? echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'afp_analysis_chart' , true), 'large' ); ?>
```

I also use the nextgen-gallery Plugin and configured it, so all images shell be applied the lightbox-effect.

The problem is, the images displayed on this teplate are not applied. How can I force this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with exactly how nextgen-gallery does it, but typically for lightbox effects you need to add `rel="lightbox"` to the image tag for it to work. To do that you'd do something like this:

```
$attr = array(
    'rel'   => "lightbox",
true) )),
);

echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'afp_analysis_chart' , true), 'large', 0, $attr );
```

Comment: that inspired me. the solution was to add the a-tag with the link to the full-image around the chart ... :)